# Why won't the Firebase package install for my Flutter app when I meet the minimum version?

Tags: firebase, terminal, dart, flutter

I am using Dart and Flutter to build a mobile app, and I'm trying to import and use outside packages (such as Firebase in this case). I followed [this dart page](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase#-installing-tab-) to install it (with the exception of changing `pub get` to `flutter packages get`) I get the following message:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.0.0-dev.58.0.flutter-f981f09760.

Because myapp depends on firebase >=4.5.1 which requires SDK version >=2.0.0-dev.61 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
```

To make sure I have to most recent version, I followed [this](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/sdk#install) (mac tab) and did

```
`$ brew upgrade dart --devel --force`
```

and got

```
`dart-lang/dart/dart 2.0.0-dev.69.5 already installed`
```

So it says I need version 2.0.0-dev.61 or higher, but it also says that I have 2.0.0-dev.69.5 installed. It seems to me that I meet the requirement and that it should work fine, so what am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you must have two versions of the sdk installed, and it's finding the old one.

Comment: @l'L'l So how do I make it find the new one?